# Get the correct value

Tags: php

I have this giant array in a function, and my mission is to send a value and match the number in the array and return the correct value in the array. The only thing i can come up with is to create a giant switch statement, is there a easier way im not thinking of? Any tips or pointers would be really helpfull.

```
function getArrayWithAllProfessions() {

            $professions = array();

            $professions['1111'] = "Politiker";
            $professions['1112'] = "General-, landstings- och kommundirektörer m.fl.";
            $professions['1113'] = "Chefstjänstemän i intresseorganisationer";
            $professions['1120'] = "Verkställande direktörer m.fl.";
            $professions['1211'] = "Ekonomi- och finanschefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1212'] = "Ekonomi- och finanschefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1221'] = "Personal- och HR-chefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1222'] = "Personal- och HR-chefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1230'] = "Förvaltnings- och planeringschefer";
            $professions['1241'] = "Informations-, kommunikations- och PR-chefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1242'] = "Informations-, kommunikations - och PR-chefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1251'] = "Försäljnings- och marknadschefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1252'] = "Försäljnings- och marknadschefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1291'] = "Övriga administrations- och servicechefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1292'] = "Övriga administrations- och servicechefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1311'] = "IT-chefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1312'] = "IT-chefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1321'] = "Inköps-, logistik- och transportchefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1322'] = "Inköps-, logistik- och transportchefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1331'] = "Forsknings- och utvecklingschefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1332'] = "Forsknings- och utvecklingschefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1341'] = "Chefer inom arkitekt- och ingenjörsverksamhet, nivå 1";
            $professions['1342'] = "Chefer inom arkitekt- och ingenjörsverksamhet, nivå 2";
            $professions['1351'] = "Fastighets- och förvaltningschefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1352'] = "Fastighets- och förvaltningschefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1361'] = "Driftchefer inom bygg, anläggning och gruva, nivå 1";
            $professions['1362'] = "Driftchefer inom bygg, anläggning och gruva, nivå 2";
            $professions['1371'] = "Produktionschefer inom tillverkning, nivå 1";
            $professions['1372'] = "Produktionschefer inom tillverkning, nivå 2";
            $professions['1380'] = "Förvaltare inom skogsbruk och lantbruk m.fl.";
            $professions['1411'] = "Avdelningschefer inom grund- och gymnasieskola samt vuxenutbildning, nivå 1";
            $professions['1412'] = "Rektorer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1421'] = "Avdelningschefer inom förskola, nivå 1";
            $professions['1422'] = "Förskolechefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1491'] = "Övriga avdelningschefer inom utbildning, nivå 1";
            $professions['1492'] = "Övriga verksamhetschefer inom utbildning, nivå 2";
            $professions['1511'] = "Klinik- och verksamhetschefer inom hälsa och sjukvård, nivå 1";
            $professions['1512'] = "Avdelnings- och enhetschefer inom hälsa och sjukvård, nivå 2";
            $professions['1521'] = "Avdelningschefer inom socialt och kurativt arbete, nivå 1";
            $professions['1522'] = "Enhetschefer inom socialt och kurativt arbete, nivå 2";
            $professions['1531'] = "Avdelningschefer inom äldreomsorg, nivå 1";
            $professions['1532'] = "Enhetschefer inom äldreomsorg, nivå 2";
            $professions['1540'] = "Chefer och ledare inom trossamfund";
            $professions['1591'] = "Övriga chefer inom samhällsservice, nivå 1";
            $professions['1592'] = "Övriga verksamhetschefer inom samhällsservice, nivå 2";
            $professions['1611'] = "Chefer inom bank, finans och försäkring, nivå 1";
            $professions['1612'] = "Chefer inom bank, finans och försäkring, nivå 2";
            $professions['1711'] = "Hotell- och konferenschefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1712'] = "Hotell- och konferenschefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1721'] = "Restaurang- och kökschefer, nivå 1";
            $professions['1722'] = "Restaurang- och kökschefer, nivå 2";
            $professions['1731'] = "Chefer inom handel, nivå 1";
            $professions['1732'] = "Chefer inom handel, nivå 2";
            $professions['1741'] = "Chefer inom friskvård, sport och fritid, nivå 1";
            $professions['1742'] = "Chefer inom friskvård, sport och fritid, nivå 2";
            $professions['1791'] = "Chefer inom övrig servicenäring, nivå 1";
            $professions['1792'] = "Chefer inom övrig servicenäring, nivå 2";
            $professions['2111'] = "Fysiker och astronomer";
            $professions['2112'] = "Meteorologer";
            $professions['2113'] = "Kemister";
            $professions['2114'] = "Geologer och geofysiker m.fl.";
            $professions['2121'] = "Matematiker och aktuarier";
            $professions['2122'] = "Statistiker";
            $professions['2131'] = "Cell- och molekylärbiologer m.fl.";
            $professions['2132'] = "Växt- och djurbiologer";
            $professions['2133'] = "Farmakologer och biomedicinare";
            $professions['2134'] = "Specialister och rådgivare inom lantbruk m.m.";
            $professions['2135'] = "Specialister och rådgivare inom skogsbruk";
            $professions['2141'] = "Civilingenjörsprofessions inom logistik och produktionsplanering";
            $professions['2142'] = "Civilingenjörsprofessions inom bygg och anläggning";
            $professions['2143'] = "Civilingenjörsprofessions inom elektroteknik";
            $professions['2144'] = "Civilingenjörsprofessions inom maskinteknik";
            $professions['2145'] = "Civilingenjörsprofessions inom kemi och kemiteknik";
            $professions['2146'] = "Civilingenjörsprofessions inom gruvteknik och metallurgi";
            $professions['2149'] = "Övriga civilingenjörsprofessions";
            $professions['2161'] = "Arkitekter m.fl.";
            $professions['2162'] = "Landskapsarkitekter";
            $professions['2163'] = "Planeringsarkitekter m.fl.";
            $professions['2164'] = "Lantmätare";
            $professions['2171'] = "Industridesigner";
            $professions['2172'] = "Grafisk formgivare m.fl.";
            $professions['2173'] = "Designer inom spel och digitala medier";
            $professions['2179'] = "Övriga designer och formgivare";
            $professions['2181'] = "Arbetsmiljöingenjörer, yrkes- och miljöhygieniker";
            $professions['2182'] = "Miljö- och hälsoskyddsinspektörer";
            $professions['2183'] = "Specialister inom miljöskydd och miljöteknik";
            $professions['2211'] = "Specialistläkare";
            $professions['2212'] = "ST-läkare";
            $professions['2213'] = "AT-läkare";
            $professions['2219'] = "Övriga läkare";
            $professions['2221'] = "Grundutbildade sjuksköterskor";
            $professions['2222'] = "Barnmorskor";
            $professions['2223'] = "Anestesisjuksköterskor";
            $professions['2224'] = "Distriktssköterskor";
            $professions['2225'] = "Psykiatrisjuksköterskor";
            $professions['2226'] = "Ambulanssjuksköterskor m.fl.";
            $professions['2227'] = "Geriatriksjuksköterskor";
            $professions['2228'] = "Intensivvårdssjuksköterskor";
            $professions['2231'] = "Operationssjuksköterskor";
            $professions['2232'] = "Barnsjuksköterskor";
            $professions['2233'] = "Skolsköterskor";
            $professions['2234'] = "Företagssköterskor";
            $professions['2235'] = "Röntgensjuksköterskor";
            $professions['2239'] = "Övriga specialistsjuksköterskor";
            $professions['2241'] = "Psykologer";
            $professions['2242'] = "Psykoterapeuter";
            $professions['2250'] = "Veterinärer";
            $professions['2260'] = "Tandläkare";
            $professions['2271'] = "Kiropraktorer och naprapater m.fl.";
            $professions['2272'] = "Sjukgymnaster";
            $professions['2273'] = "Arbetsterapeuter";
            $professions['2281'] = "Apotekare";
            $professions['2282'] = "Dietister";
            $professions['2283'] = "Audionomer och logopeder";
            $professions['2284'] = "Optiker";
            $professions['2289'] = "Övriga specialister inom hälso- och sjukvård";
            $professions['2311'] = "Professorer";
            $professions['2312'] = "Universitets- och högskolelektorer";
            $professions['2313'] = "Forskarassistenter m.fl.";
            $professions['2314'] = "Doktorander";
            $professions['2319'] = "Övriga universitets- och högskollärare";
            $professions['2320'] = "Lärare i yrkesämnen";
            $professions['2330'] = "Gymnasielärare";
            $professions['2341'] = "Grundskollärare";
            $professions['2342'] = "Fritidspedagoger";
            $professions['2343'] = "Förskollärare";
            $professions['2351'] = "Speciallärare och specialpedagoger m.fl.";
            $professions['2352'] = "Studie- och yrkesvägledare";
            $professions['2359'] = "Övriga pedagoger med teoretisk specialistkompetens";
            $professions['2411'] = "Revisorer m.fl.";
            $professions['2412'] = "Controller";
            $professions['2413'] = "Finansanalytiker och investeringsrådgivare m.fl.";
            $professions['2414'] = "Traders och fondförvaltare";
            $professions['2415'] = "Nationalekonomer och makroanalytiker m.fl.";
            $professions['2419'] = "Övriga ekonomer";
            $professions['2421'] = "Lednings- och organisationsutvecklare";
            $professions['2422'] = "Planerare och utredare m.fl.";
            $professions['2423'] = "Personal- och HR-specialister";
            $professions['2431'] = "Marknadsanalytiker och marknadsförare m.fl.";
            $professions['2432'] = "Informatörer, kommunikatörer och PR-specialister";
            $professions['2511'] = "Systemanalytiker och IT-arkitekter m.fl.";
            $professions['2512'] = "Mjukvaru- och systemutvecklare m.fl.";
            $professions['2513'] = "Utvecklare inom spel och digitala media";
            $professions['2514'] = "Systemtestare och testledare";
            $professions['2515'] = "Systemförvaltare m.fl.";
            $professions['2516'] = "IT-säkerhetsspecialister";
            $professions['2519'] = "Övriga IT-specialister";
            $professions['2611'] = "Advokater";
            $professions['2612'] = "Domare";
            $professions['2613'] = "Åklagare";
            $professions['2614'] = "Affärs- och företagsjurister";
            $professions['2615'] = "Förvaltnings- och organisationsjurister";
            $professions['2619'] = "Övriga jurister";
            $professions['2621'] = "Museiintendenter m.fl.";
            $professions['2622'] = "Bibliotekarier och arkivarier";
            $professions['2623'] = "Arkeologer och specialister inom humaniora m.m.";
            $professions['2641'] = "Författare m.fl.";
            $professions['2642'] = "Journalister m.fl.";
            $professions['2643'] = "Översättare, tolkar och lingvister m.fl.";
            $professions['2651'] = "Bildkonstnärer m.fl.";
            $professions['2652'] = "Musiker, sångare och kompositörer";
            $professions['2653'] = "Koreografer och dansare";
            $professions['2654'] = "Regissörer och producenter av film, teater m.m.";
            $professions['2655'] = "Skådespelare";
            $professions['2661'] = "Socialsekreterare";
            $professions['2662'] = "Kuratorer";
            $professions['2663'] = "Biståndsbedömare m.fl.";
            $professions['2669'] = "Övriga yrken inom socialt arbete";
            $professions['2671'] = "Präster";
            $professions['2672'] = "Diakoner";
            $professions['3111'] = "Ingenjörer och tekniker inom industri, logistik och produktionsplanering";
            $professions['3112'] = "Ingenjörer och tekniker inom bygg och anläggning";
            $professions['3113'] = "Ingenjörer och tekniker inom elektroteknik";
            $professions['3114'] = "Ingenjörer och tekniker inom maskinteknik";
            $professions['3115'] = "Ingenjörer och tekniker inom kemi och kemiteknik";
            $professions['3116'] = "Ingenjörer och tekniker inom gruvteknik och metallurgi";
            $professions['3117'] = "GIS- och kartingenjörer";
            $professions['3119'] = "Övriga ingenjörer och tekniker";
            $professions['3121'] = "Arbetsledare inom bygg, anläggning och gruva";
            $professions['3122'] = "Arbetsledare inom tillverkning";
            $professions['3151'] = "Maskinbefäl";
            $professions['3152'] = "Fartygsbefäl m.fl.";
            $professions['3153'] = "Piloter m.fl.";
            $professions['3154'] = "Flygledare";
            $professions['3155'] = "Flygtekniker";
            $professions['3211'] = "Tekniker, bilddiagnostik och medicinteknisk utrustning";
            $professions['3212'] = "Biomedicinska analytiker m.fl.";
            $professions['3213'] = "Receptarier";
            $professions['3214'] = "Tandtekniker och ortopedingenjörer m.fl.";
            $professions['3215'] = "Laboratorieingenjörer";
            $professions['3230'] = "Terapeuter inom alternativmedicin";
            $professions['3240'] = "Djursjukskötare m.fl.";
            $professions['3250'] = "Tandhygienister";
            $professions['3311'] = "Mäklare inom finans";
            $professions['3312'] = "Banktjänstemän";
            $professions['3313'] = "Redovisningsekonomer";
            $professions['3314'] = "Skadereglerare och värderare";
            $professions['3321'] = "Försäkringssäljare och försäkringsrådgivare";
            $professions['3322'] = "Företagssäljare";
            $professions['3323'] = "Inköpare och upphandlare";
            $professions['3324'] = "Ordersamordnare m.fl.";
            $professions['3331'] = "Speditörer och transportmäklare";
            $professions['3332'] = "Evenemangs- och reseproducenter m.fl.";
            $professions['3333'] = "Arbetsförmedlare";
            $professions['3334'] = "Fastighetsmäklare";
            $professions['3335'] = "Fastighetsförvaltare";
            $professions['3339'] = "Övriga förmedlare";
            $professions['3341'] = "Gruppledare för kontorspersonal";
            $professions['3342'] = "Domstols- och juristsekreterare m.fl.";
            $professions['3343'] = "Chefssekreterare och VD-assistenter m.fl.";
            $professions['3351'] = "Tull- och kustbevakningstjänstemän";
            $professions['3352'] = "Skattehandläggare";
            $professions['3353'] = "Socialförsäkringshandläggare";
            $professions['3354'] = "Säkerhetsinspektörer m.fl.";
            $professions['3355'] = "Brandingenjörer och byggnadsinspektörer m.fl.";
            $professions['3359'] = "Övriga handläggare";
            $professions['3360'] = "Poliser";
            $professions['3411'] = "Behandlingsassistenter och socialpedagoger m.fl.";
            $professions['3412'] = "Pastorer m.fl.";
            $professions['3421'] = "Professionella idrottsutövare";
            $professions['3422'] = "Idrottstränare och instruktörer m.fl.";
            $professions['3423'] = "Fritidsledare m.fl.";
            $professions['3424'] = "Friskvårdskonsulenter och hälsopedagoger m.fl.";
            $professions['3431'] = "Fotografer";
            $professions['3432'] = "Inredare, dekoratörer och scenografer m.fl.";
            $professions['3433'] = "Inspicienter och scriptor m.fl.";
            $professions['3439'] = "Övriga yrken inom kultur och underhållning";
            $professions['3441'] = "Trafiklärare";
            $professions['3449'] = "Övriga utbildare och instruktörer";
            $professions['3451'] = "Köksmästare och souschefer";
            $professions['3452'] = "Storhushållsföreståndare";
            $professions['3511'] = "Drifttekniker, IT";
            $professions['3512'] = "Supporttekniker, IT";
            $professions['3513'] = "Systemadministratörer";
            $professions['3514'] = "Nätverks- och systemtekniker m.fl.";
            $professions['3515'] = "Webbmaster och webbadministratörer";
            $professions['3521'] = "Bild- och sändningstekniker";
            $professions['3522'] = "Ljus-, ljud och scentekniker";
            $professions['4111'] = "Ekonomiassistenter m.fl.";
            $professions['4112'] = "Löne- och personaladministratörer";
            $professions['4113'] = "Backofficepersonal m.fl.";
            $professions['4114'] = "Marknads- och försäljningsassistenter";
            $professions['4115'] = "Inköps- och orderassistenter";
            $professions['4116'] = "Skolassistenter m.fl.";
            $professions['4117'] = "Medicinska sekreterare, vårdadministratörer m.fl.";
            $professions['4119'] = "Övriga kontorsassistenter och sekreterare";
            $professions['4211'] = "Croupierer och oddssättare m.fl.";
            $professions['4212'] = "Inkasserare och pantlånare m.fl.";
            $professions['4221'] = "Resesäljare och trafikassistenter m.fl.";
            $professions['4222'] = "Kundtjänstpersonal";
            $professions['4223'] = "Telefonister";
            $professions['4224'] = "Hotellreceptionister m.fl.";
            $professions['4225'] = "Kontorsreceptionister";
            $professions['4226'] = "Marknadsundersökare och intervjuare";
            $professions['4321'] = "Arbetsledare inom lager och terminal";
            $professions['4322'] = "Lager- och terminalpersonal";
            $professions['4323'] = "Transportledare och transportsamordnare";
            $professions['4410'] = "Biblioteks- och arkivassistenter m.fl.";
            $professions['4420'] = "Brevbärare och postterminalarbetare";
            $professions['4430'] = "Förtroendevalda";
            $professions['5111'] = "Kabinpersonal m.fl.";
            $professions['5112'] = "Tågvärdar och ombordansvariga m.fl.";
            $professions['5113'] = "Guider och reseledare";
            $professions['5120'] = "Kockar och kallskänkor";
            $professions['5131'] = "Hovmästare och servitörer";
            $professions['5132'] = "Bartendrar";
            $professions['5141'] = "Frisörer";
            $professions['5142'] = "Hudterapeuter";
            $professions['5143'] = "Massörer och massageterapeuter";
            $professions['5144'] = "Fotterapeuter";
            $professions['5149'] = "Övriga skönhets- och kroppsterapeuter";
            $professions['5151'] = "Städledare och husfruar";
            $professions['5152'] = "Fastighetsskötare";
            $professions['5161'] = "Begravnings- och krematoriepersonal";
            $professions['5169'] = "Övrig servicepersonal";
            $professions['5221'] = "Säljande butikschefer och avdelningschefer i butik";
            $professions['5222'] = "Butikssäljare, dagligvaror";
            $professions['5223'] = "Butikssäljare, fackhandel";
            $professions['5224'] = "Optikerassistenter";
            $professions['5225'] = "Bensinstationspersonal";
            $professions['5226'] = "Uthyrare";
            $professions['5227'] = "Apotekstekniker";
            $professions['5230'] = "Kassapersonal m.fl.";
            $professions['5241'] = "Eventsäljare och butiksdemonstratörer m.fl.";
            $professions['5242'] = "Telefonförsäljare m.fl.";
            $professions['5311'] = "Barnskötare";
            $professions['5312'] = "Elevassistenter m.fl.";
            $professions['5321'] = "Undersköterskor, hemtjänst, hemsjukvård och äldreboende";
            $professions['5322'] = "Undersköterskor, habilitering";
            $professions['5323'] = "Undersköterskor, vård- och specialavdelning";
            $professions['5324'] = "Undersköterskor, mottagning";
            $professions['5325'] = "Barnsköterskor";
            $professions['5326'] = "Ambulanssjukvårdare";
            $professions['5330'] = "Vårdbiträden";
            $professions['5341'] = "Skötare";
            $professions['5342'] = "Vårdare, boendestödjare";
            $professions['5343'] = "Personliga assistenter";
            $professions['5349'] = "Övrig vård- och omsorgspersonal";
            $professions['5350'] = "Tandsköterskor";
            $professions['5411'] = "Brandmän";
            $professions['5412'] = "Kriminalvårdare";
            $professions['5413'] = "Väktare och ordningsvakter";
            $professions['5414'] = "SOS-operatörer m.fl.";
            $professions['5419'] = "Övrig bevaknings- och säkerhetspersonal";
            $professions['6111'] = "Odlare av jordbruksväxter, frukt- och bär";
            $professions['6112'] = "Trädgårdsodlare";
            $professions['6113'] = "Trädgårdsanläggare m.fl.";
            $professions['6121'] = "Uppfödare och skötare av lantbrukets husdjur";
            $professions['6122'] = "Uppfödare och skötare av sällskapsdjur";
            $professions['6129'] = "Övriga djuruppfödare och djurskötare";
            $professions['6130'] = "Växtodlare och djuruppfödare, blandad drift";
            $professions['6210'] = "Skogsarbetare";
            $professions['6221'] = "Fiskodlare";
            $professions['6222'] = "Fiskare";
            $professions['7111'] = "Träarbetare, snickare m.fl.";
            $professions['7112'] = "Murare m.fl.";
            $professions['7113'] = "Betongarbetare";
            $professions['7114'] = "Anläggningsarbetare";
            $professions['7115'] = "Anläggningsdykare";
            $professions['7116'] = "Ställningsbyggare";
            $professions['7119'] = "Övriga byggnads- och anläggningsarbetare";
            $professions['7121'] = "Takmontörer";
            $professions['7122'] = "Golvläggare";
            $professions['7123'] = "Isoleringsmontörer";
            $professions['7124'] = "Glastekniker";
            $professions['7125'] = "VVS-montörer m.fl.";
            $professions['7126'] = "Kyl- och värmepumpstekniker m.fl.";
            $professions['7131'] = "Målare";
            $professions['7132'] = "Lackerare och industrimålare";
            $professions['7133'] = "Skorstensfejare";
            $professions['7134'] = "Saneringsarbetare m.fl.";
            $professions['7211'] = "Gjutare";
            $professions['7212'] = "Svetsare och gasskärare";
            $professions['7213'] = "Byggnads- och ventilationsplåtslagare";
            $professions['7214'] = "Tunnplåtslagare";
            $professions['7215'] = "Stålkonstruktionsmontörer och grovplåtsslagare";
            $professions['7221'] = "Smeder";
            $professions['7222'] = "Verktygsmakare";
            $professions['7223'] = "Maskinställare och maskinoperatörer, metallarbete";
            $professions['7224'] = "Slipare m.fl.";
            $professions['7231'] = "Motorfordonsmekaniker och fordonsreparatörer";
            $professions['7232'] = "Flygmekaniker m.fl.";
            $professions['7233'] = "Underhållsmekaniker och maskinreparatörer";
            $professions['7311'] = "Finmekaniker";
            $professions['7312'] = "Guld- och silversmeder";
            $professions['7319'] = "Musikinstrumentmakare och övriga konsthantverkare";
            $professions['7321'] = "Prepresstekniker";
            $professions['7322'] = "Tryckare";
            $professions['7323'] = "Bokbindare m.fl.";
            $professions['7411'] = "Installations- och serviceelektriker";
            $professions['7412'] = "Industrielektriker";
            $professions['7413'] = "Distributionselektriker";
            $professions['7420'] = "Elektronikreparatörer och kommunikationselektriker m.fl.";
            $professions['7521'] = "Manuella ytbehandlare, trä";
            $professions['7522'] = "Fin-, inrednings- och möbelsnickare";
            $professions['7523'] = "Maskinsnickare och maskinoperatörer, träindustri";
            $professions['7531'] = "Skräddare och ateljésömmerskor m.fl.";
            $professions['7532'] = "Sömmare";
            $professions['7533'] = "Tapetserare";
            $professions['7534'] = "Läderhantverkare och skomakare";
            $professions['7611'] = "Slaktare och styckare m.fl.";
            $professions['7612'] = "Bagare och konditorer";
            $professions['7613'] = "Provsmakare och kvalitetsbedömare";
            $professions['7619'] = "Övriga livsmedelsförädlare";
            $professions['8111'] = "Gruv- och stenbrottsarbetare";
            $professions['8112'] = "Processoperatörer, stenkross- och malmförädlingsanläggning";
            $professions['8113'] = "Brunnsborrare m.fl.";
            $professions['8114'] = "Maskinoperatörer, cement-, sten- och betongvaror";
            $professions['8115'] = "Bergssprängare";
            $professions['8116'] = "Stenhuggare m.fl.";
            $professions['8121'] = "Maskinoperatörer, ytbehandling";
            $professions['8122'] = "Valsverksoperatörer";
            $professions['8129'] = "Övriga maskin- och processoperatörer vid stål- och metallverk";
            $professions['8131'] = "Maskinoperatörer, farmaceutiska produkter";
            $professions['8132'] = "Maskinoperatörer, kemisktekniska och fotografiska produkter";
            $professions['8141'] = "Maskinoperatörer, gummiindustri";
            $professions['8142'] = "Maskinoperatörer, plastindustri";
            $professions['8143'] = "Maskinoperatörer, pappersvaruindustri";
            $professions['8151'] = "Maskinoperatörer, blekning, färgning och tvättning";
            $professions['8159'] = "Övriga maskinoperatörer, textil-, skinn- och läderindustri";
            $professions['8161'] = "Maskinoperatörer, kött- och fiskberedningsindustri";
            $professions['8162'] = "Maskinoperatörer, mejeri";
            $professions['8163'] = "Maskinoperatörer, kvarn-, bageri- och konfektyrindustri";
            $professions['8169'] = "Övriga maskinoperatörer inom livsmedelsindustri m.m.";
            $professions['8171'] = "Processoperatörer, pappersmassa";
            $professions['8172'] = "Processoperatörer, papper";
            $professions['8173'] = "Operatörer inom sågverk, hyvleri och plywood m.m.";
            $professions['8174'] = "Maskinoperatörer inom ytbehandling, trä";
            $professions['8181'] = "Maskinoperatörer, påfyllning, packning och märkning";
            $professions['8189'] = "Andra process- och maskinoperatörer";
            $professions['8191'] = "Drifttekniker vid värme- och vattenverk";
            $professions['8192'] = "Processövervakare, kemisk industri";
            $professions['8193'] = "Processövervakare, metallproduktion";
            $professions['8199'] = "Övriga drifttekniker och processövervakare";
            $professions['8211'] = "Fordonsmontörer";
            $professions['8212'] = "Montörer, elektrisk och elektronisk utrustning";
            $professions['8213'] = "Montörer, metall-, gummi- och plastprodukter";
            $professions['8214'] = "Montörer, träprodukter";
            $professions['8219'] = "Övriga montörer";
            $professions['8311'] = "Lokförare";
            $professions['8312'] = "Bangårdspersonal";
            $professions['8321'] = "Taxiförare m.fl.";
            $professions['8329'] = "Övriga bil-, motorcykel- och cykelförare";
            $professions['8331'] = "Buss- och spårvagnsförare";
            $professions['8332'] = "Lastbilsförare m.fl.";
            $professions['8341'] = "Förare av jordbruks- och skogsmaskiner";
            $professions['8342'] = "Anläggningsmaskinförare m.fl.";
            $professions['8343'] = "Kranförare m.fl.";
            $professions['8344'] = "Truckförare";
            $professions['8350'] = "Matroser och jungmän m.fl.";
            $professions['9111'] = "Städare";
            $professions['9119'] = "Övrig hemservicepersonal m.fl.";
            $professions['9120'] = "Bilrekonditionerare, fönsterputsare och övriga rengöringsarbetare";
            $professions['9210'] = "Bärplockare och plantörer m.fl.";
            $professions['9310'] = "Grovarbetare inom bygg och anläggning";
            $professions['9320'] = "Handpaketerare och andra fabriksarbetare";
            $professions['9331'] = "Hamnarbetare";
            $professions['9332'] = "Ramppersonal, flyttkarlar och varupåfyllare m.fl.";
            $professions['9411'] = "Pizzabagare m.fl.";
            $professions['9412'] = "Restaurang- och köksbiträden m.fl.";
            $professions['9413'] = "Kafé- och konditoribiträden";
            $professions['9520'] = "Torg- och marknadsförsäljare";
            $professions['9610'] = "Renhållnings- och återvinningsarbetare";
            $professions['9621'] = "Reklamutdelare och tidningsdistributörer";
            $professions['9622'] = "Vaktmästare m.fl.";
            $professions['9629'] = "Övriga servicearbetare";
            $professions['0110'] = "Officerare";
            $professions['0210'] = "Specialistofficerare";
            $professions['0310'] = "Soldater m.fl.";

            asort($professions);

            return $professions;
        }
```

Comment: `return $professions[$x];` ?

Comment: check if $professions[$x] exist and return

Comment: $value = 1211; echo $professions[$value]  (this return Ekonomi- och finanschefer, nivå 1), is that the thing you want?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! That is what i want! L. Antonelli

Comment: I hope you are going to use a database for this information rather than a hardcoded array.

Answer (score 1):

The first think about something like:

```
$professions = [
    '0005' => 'Example',
    '0006' => 'Another example',
];
```

Then you can check it by:

```
return empty($professions[$identifier]) ? null : $professions[$identifier];
```

or (php7+)

```
return $professions[$identifier] ?? null;
```

Tip1: Better way is throwing exception when not found.

Tip2: If you are using framework (ex. Symfony) - try to move this configuration into yaml and pass to constructor of collection by dependency injection `%professions%` etc.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way by utilizing the `array_key_exists()` function.

```
function getArrayWithAllProfessions($value) {

  $professions = array();

  $professions['1111'] = "Politiker";
  $professions['1112'] = "General-, landstings- och kommundirektörer m.fl.";
  $professions['1113'] = "Chefstjänstemän i intresseorganisationer";
  $professions['1120'] = "Verkställande direktörer m.fl.";
  $professions['1211'] = "Ekonomi- och finanschefer, nivå 1";

  return array_key_exists($value, $professions) ? $professions[$value] : FALSE;


}

echo getArrayWithAllProfessions('1112') . '<br>'; //<-- General-, landstings- och kommundirektörer m.fl.
echo getArrayWithAllProfessions('1120') . '<br>'; //<-- Verkställande direktörer m.fl.
var_dump(getArrayWithAllProfessions('0123')) . '<br>'; //<- FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

function getProfession($key) {

  $professions = [
    '0001' => 'Butcher',
    '0002' => 'Baker',
    '0003' => 'Candlestick Maker',
    '0004' => null,
    'null' => 'Doctor'
  ];


  $retval = isset($professions[$key]) || array_key_exists($key,$professions)? $professions[$key] : false;
  return $retval;

}

echo getProfession("0001"),"\n"; // Butcher
echo getProfession('0002'),"\n"; // Baker
echo getProfession('0003'),"\n";  // Candlestick Maker
var_dump( getProfession('0004'));  // null
echo getProfession('null'),"\n"; // Doctor
var_dump(getProfession('246'));  // bool(false)
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/kpMhG)

User-defined getProfession() takes one parameter, namely a key to seek in an array listing various professions.  While [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/array_key_exists) can ably determine whether a key exists, this built-in function can be slow. A user at php.net suggests a helpful approach [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#107786) which the code incorporates with a statement testing whether an array element is set. But, isset() returns false if an array element's value is null. So, to obtain a more accurate result, array_key_exists() then executes. Consquently,`$retval` will be set to the profession contained in the key's corresponding element value or else to false if the key actually does not exist in the array.  Lastly, the function returns `$retval` for display.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers, please add some explanation.

Comment: You can do something like `return $professions[$key] ?? false;` instead of two lines.

Comment: @PatrykWoziński's suggestion unfortunately is less than satisfactory when the associative array contains a null value.  Instead of retrieving that value the result is false; see https://3v4l.org/8BaAa.  While his upvoted answer seems practical with respect to PHP7, it misses the subtle distinction between an unset element in an array and an element that does not exist in an array; see https://3v4l.org/cN5or